# Testing a lot of external APIs in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, testing, integration-testing

I'm developing a Rails app with a lot of dependencies on external APIs, for example Delicious. 
All APIs share two workflows:

- On the first call they are going to load all data since the beginning of time.
- All following calls will load data filtered by the last execution time (if supported).

Testing them in real means I must create a test account for each API or at least use my private one. Even with [`VCR`](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr), because they would be called once. And my biggest problem: I would have to mess around a lot with `Date`'s and `Time`'s to emulate the two different workflows mentioned above. Though [`Timecop`](https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop) makes it really easy, it feels like a pain in the ass.

Another approach is to fake the API calls and their corresponding responses completely, but this means no real tests and furthermore I would never realize changes or problems with the APIs.

Any suggestions? Maybe a good combination of both ways?

Answer (score 1):

Do both.

Start by mocking/stubbing everything in your regular run-frequently test suite. Do this for all the fine-grained model/controller testing.

Then add end-to-end testing (eg in integration tests) that cover usual workflow-scenarios that hit the real (test) servers.

Alternatively use a different test suite for the end-to-end testing eg cucumber instead of Test::Unit, or selenium/Watir whatever as long as it's different to your usual test suite